# Java ProcessBuilder and VBS script issue

Tags: java, vbscript, processbuilder

Am going round in circles here trying to execute a bit of VBScript from java using processbuilder.  I'm running my java code as part of a tomcat servlet.  If I run the same command from a command line - its running fine.  Have tried opening permissions right up (everyone=full perms)

Java Code (excerpt):

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cscript", "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\office2pdf.vbs", "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\temp\\22.doc");
Process pr = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
String line = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
int i = pr.waitFor() ;
getServletContext().log("pb response="+i+", er="+sb.toString());
```

VBScript (excerpt):

```vb
Sub SaveWordAsPDF(p_strFilePath)
    'Save Word file as a PDF

    'Initialise
    Dim objWord, objDocument
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     Wscript.Echo p_strFilePath
    'Open the file
    Set objDocument = objWord.Documents.Open(p_strFilePath)

    'Save the PDF
    objDocument.SaveAs PathOfPDF(p_strFilePath), WORD_PDF

    'Close the file and exit the application
    objDocument.Close FALSE
    objWord.Quit
End Sub
```

I've traced it as far to see that the vbscript is infact loading; the line 'Wscript.Echo p_strFilePath' does in fact actually print the correct path to the word doc.  According to the error stream returned from java the offending line from vbscript is: 'Set objDocument = objWord.Documents.Open(p_strFilePath)' for which its saying:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'objWord.Documents.Open(...)'

not sure if this is only triggered from incomplete path; looked at lots of posts - haven't been able to find any that exactly match my situation.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is Tomcat running as a service? If so, then the `System` user it's running as, is perhaps not allowed to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Server-side use of Office is not supported and not recommended, see this advice from Microsoft :  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757 . Note that it's possible to make it work but it is extremely fragile.

Comment: @andreas - yes it is running as a service; & good point; I will double check - however I did already try opening the permissions right up

Comment: Didn't figure this one out which was annoying; cause I've had it working on LAMP stack before.. anyhow.. RealHowTo is right though I think; shame, cause other libraries don't get the precision that MS Office gets with PDF conversion; Open office has come a long way though since I last used it for this purpose & obviously ties in nicely with java SDK.. gonna stick with that.